# How do I launch the recent apps programmatically?

Tags: java, android, background, launch

- can anyone give me help:
  I have put this code is work well if my app is last app opened. but if I open other app after my app, she's stays in background.
- if anyone can give me how I can run my application as if it's the last open application or something else like its.

code:

```
public void Show_App(String packageName){

this.activity.getWindow().addFlags(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON|
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD|
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED|
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);


Intent startIntent = 
        context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
startIntent.setFlags(           
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED
);
this.context.startActivity(startIntent);
}
```

Comment: what is the error.?

Comment: NO error but i need add something to my code to run my app all time on top

Answer (score 0):

```
private void getRecentAppList() {

    ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RecentTaskInfo> recentTasks = mActivityManager.getRecentTasks(10, 0);
    for (ActivityManager.RecentTaskInfo taskInfo : recentTasks) {
String packagename = task.baseIntent.getComponent().getPackageName();
        Intent intent = taskInfo.baseIntent;
        ResolveInfo resolveInfo = mPackageManager.resolveActivity(intent, 0);
        ActivityInfo activityInfo = resolveInfo.activityInfo;
    } }
```

**you didn't close or clear app in recent list** than recent app lunch list is get.